# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool' pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Actually i was trying to copy few columns from a dataframe to another dataframe but got an error unsupported operand type for & float and bool pandas

```
df
df
mask_actor = df[df.cast.str.contains("Bruce Willis")]
mask_genres = df[df.genres.str.contains("Adventure")& df.genres.str.contains("Family")]
from IPython.display import HTML
bruce=df.loc[mask_actor &mask_genres,["title","vote_average"]].sort_values(by ="vote_average",ascending =False)
sup = HTML(bruce.to_html(escape= False))
sup
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Is the call to `HTML()` really relevant to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Substituting boolean mask to dataframe gives you the filtered dataframe. You need just to save mask `df.cast.str.contains("Bruce Willis")` in `mask_actor` (without performing filtration) (and do the same with `mask_genres` variables).

The full working snippet should look like this:

```py
mask_actor = df.cast.str.contains("Bruce Willis")
mask_genres = df.genres.str.contains("Adventure") & df.genres.str.contains("Family")
from IPython.display import HTML
bruce = df.loc[mask_actor &mask_genres,["title","vote_average"]].sort_values(by ="vote_average",ascending =False)
sup = HTML(bruce.to_html(escape= False))
sup
```